# What sort of cord do I need to fix my wired Xbox One controller?

Tags: controllers, xbox-one

Back in December my parents got my a new wired Xbox One controller. Recently, its cord broke and I cannot find a replacement. The issue is that inside the port it has this little bit that comes up. If you try to put a normal cord in then it catches the big and won't go into the actual port.

My parents and I have scoured Amazon for the cord, for the controller, even Google but to no avail. So I have no idea where to get a replacement for the cord.

So I'm looking for a cord that won't be caught by the big and will be able to charge the controller.

Comment: Hi, can you share some relevant pictures of the controller? The part that you're talking about, the controller information from the back, that sort of thing.

Comment: Hi, you mention "a new wired Xbox One controller". Are you sure that this is an official Xbox One Controller? Maybe is a [PowerA Enhanced](https://www.powera.com/products/enhanced-wired-controller-for-xbox-one-black/), an officially licensed controller that is wired only but has a detachable USB cable (it can't be the AmazonBasics one, because the wire is not not detachable).

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue. If your controller is one of the 'PowerA Enhanced' licensed models, you could try the Replacement USB Cable for PowerA controllers from their [official site](https://www.powera.com/product/replacement-usb-cable-for-powera-wired-controllers/).

Another potential solution is you could try filing down the little notch that stops other cables from fitting correctly.

Comment: i wouldn't recommend filing it down since you risk damaging wires and whatnot in the jack itself if you go too far down, especially given the size of some cable ends.

Answer (score -3):

Your normal USB type b that's all!

Comment: Not what in talking about lol. I'll post some pictures...

Answer (score -3):

You have to get a chord w/micro USB to USB A, and be sure the micro USB side is "fat" (from top to bottom) and not  the thin and "smooshed wide" type. Standard Android phone-charger cable with a "fat" rather than sleek micro USB end. The "sleek" ones are two wide to fit; the fat ones WILL fit once you remove the notch in the PowerA controller. You need to heat up a flat-blade screwdriver on your stovetop, lighter, or propane torch, and melt away the obnoxious notch in the PowerA controller.